# logging into moodle using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, moodle

I'm trying to write some code that downloads content from Moodle website.
the first thing was trying and logging in, but from what I've tried so far, it seems as if I'm not actually being redirected to the page after log in (with the courses data etc...). here's that I've tried

```
user = 'my_username'
pas = 'my_password'
payload = {'username':user, 'password':pas}


login_site = "https://moodle2....?" # actual login webpage
data_site = "https://moodle2...." # should be the inner webpage with the courses etc...
    
with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(login_site, data=payload)
    r = session.get(data_site)
    content = r.text
    print(content) # doesn't actually contain the HTML of the main courses page (seems to me its the login page)
```

any idea why might that happen? would appreciate your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help without knowing more about the specific site you are trying to log into.

One thing that's worth a try is changing

```
session.post(login_site, data=payload)
```

to

```
session.post(login_site, json=payload)
```

When the `data` parameter is used, the `content-type` header is not set to "application/json". Some sites will reject the POST based on this.

I've also run into sites which have protections against logins from scripts. They may require an additional token to be sent in the POST.

If all else fails, you could consider using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Selenium allows you to control a browser instance programmatically You can simply load the page and send text input to the username and password fields on the login page. This would also get you access to any content which is rendered client side via javascript. However, this may be overkill depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [answer (not in python)](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=382965) an additional login-token is needed. This token is given in the HTML of the login screen.

Theo following sample code does the trick, I used regex to extract the token, you could also use beautiful soup or other tools...

```
s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url_login)
match = re.search(r'name="logintoken" value="(.+?)"', r.text)
if match:
    login_token = match.group(1)
    # print(login_token)

# you'll have to define variables for username and password
login_data = {'logintoken': login_token, 'username': username, 'password': passwort}

r = s.post(url_login, login_data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```